# Lie algebra of lorentz group

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lie-algebra

I'm stuck in following calcualtion from sredniki's QFT book.(Its actually in the solution manual)

How can i get from

$$\delta\omega_{\rho\sigma}(g^{\sigma\mu}M^{\rho\nu} - g^{\rho\nu}M^{\mu\sigma})
$$

to

$$
\frac{1}{2}\delta\omega_{\rho\sigma}(g^{\sigma\mu}M^{\rho\nu} - g^{\rho\nu}M^{\mu\sigma} -g^{\rho\mu}M^{\sigma\nu} + g^{\sigma\nu}M^{\mu\rho})
$$

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28535/2451

Comment: That question and the answers given are a bit formal. Thanks for noticing it. I'm going through it and also try to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\delta \omega_{\rho\sigma}$ is antisymmetric, the part of what's inside the parentheses symmetrized over $\rho$ and $\sigma$ will vanish because if you contract antisymmetric indices with symmetric ones, you get zero.  So you can anti-symmetrize over that pair of indices inside the parentheses without changing anything, which is precisely what's inside the parentheses in the second line:

\begin{align}
\delta \omega_{\rho \sigma} (g^{\sigma \mu} M^{\rho \nu} - g^{\rho \mu} M^{\sigma \nu})
&=
\delta \omega_{\rho \sigma} \bigg[ \frac{1}{2} (g^{\sigma\mu}M^{\rho\nu} - g^{\rho\nu}M^{\mu\sigma} -g^{\rho\mu}M^{\sigma\nu} + g^{\sigma\nu}M^{\mu\rho})
\\
& \qquad \qquad +\frac{1}{2} (g^{\sigma\mu}M^{\rho\nu} - g^{\rho\nu}M^{\mu\sigma} + g^{\rho\mu}M^{\sigma\nu} - g^{\sigma\nu}M^{\mu\rho}) \bigg]
\end{align}

Here, I've just split the $gM$ factor into parts antisymmetric and symmetric in $\rho \sigma$.  (You can check that the terms inside the brackets cancel directly to give the same thing as the left-hand side.)  It's an easy exercise to check that for a general symmetric tensor $T^{\rho\sigma}$, you have $\delta \omega_{\rho \sigma}T^{\rho\sigma}=0$.  Adding more indices to $T$ doesn't change that, so the second term inside the brackets just drops out, and you get your result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes $\delta\omega$ is anti-symmetric.

Comment: Sure thing.  I've added a little more explanation.  Don't forget to accept it if this satisfies you.  :)