# Massaging an infinitesimal Lorentz transformation into a divergence

Tags: special-relativity

So, I was watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cj-QpsZsDDY&t=3968s , where at some point the prof explains that a divergence can be ontained by "exploiting the antisymmetry" of an infinitesimal Lorentz transformation.

What it boils down to is this:
Let $x^\mu$ be some inertial coordinate system in flat 4D spacetime with Minkowstki metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$. Consider the infinitesimal Lorentz transformation
$$
x'^\mu=\Lambda^\mu_{\;\nu}x^\nu=(\delta^\mu_{\;\nu}+\omega^\mu_{\;\nu})x^\nu
$$
with $|\omega^\mu_{\;\nu}| \ll 1$. It is easy to show (see e.g. [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/87346/infinitesimal-lorentz-transformation-is-antisymmetric)) that this requires that $\omega^{\mu\sigma}=\eta^{\sigma\nu}\omega^\mu_{\;\nu}$ be antisymmetric.

Now here's my question: apparently this antisymmetry allows one to conclude, that
$$
\partial_\mu(\omega^\mu_{\;\nu} x^\nu)=0
$$
Yet, I can't manage to prove that. Here's what I came up with sofar
$$
\partial_\mu(\omega^\mu_{\;\nu} x^\nu)=\partial_\mu(\omega^{\mu\sigma}\eta_{\sigma\nu}x^\nu) \\
=\frac{1}{2}\eta_{\sigma\nu}\partial_\mu(\omega^{\mu\sigma}x^\nu)-\frac{1}{2}\eta_{\sigma\nu}\partial_\mu(\omega^{\sigma\mu}x^\nu) \\
=\frac{1}{2}\eta_{\sigma\nu}\partial_\mu(\omega^{\mu\sigma}x^\nu)-\frac{1}{2}\eta_{\mu\nu}\partial_\sigma(\omega^{\mu\sigma}x^\nu)
$$

none of which seems to bring me any closer though... Am a missing something trivial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, never mind. I did indeed miss something completely trivial. In my scenario, the $\omega^\mu_{\;\nu}$'s are *constant*; I've just been doing far too much general relativity lately, where everything depends on position ;)

Anyway, remembering that $\partial_\sigma \omega^\mu_{\;\nu}=0$, the proof is indeed trivial:

$$
\partial_\mu(\omega^\mu_{\;\nu} x^\nu)=\omega^\mu_{\;\nu}\partial_\mu x^\nu=\omega^{\mu\sigma}\eta_{\sigma\nu}\delta^\nu_{\;\mu}=\omega^{\mu\sigma}\eta_{\sigma\mu}=0
$$
since $\eta_{\sigma\mu}$ is symmetric. My bad.

By the way, anyone interested in the original issue, which is finding the conserved currents in a scalar field, generated by Lorentz symmetries, can also look at [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/135277/the-variation-of-the-lagrangian-density-under-an-infinitesimal-lorentz-transform?rq=1), which I just found. It confirms, among other things, my solution here.

Comment: Moral: stop doing general relativity? :p

Comment: Absolutely not. I love general relativity :)