# What does a left-right arrow in a tensor formula mean?

Tags: tensor-calculus, notation, commutator

I need help with some some notation I've not seen before. 
Is using the left-right arrow in this formula 
$$[P^μ,M^{ρσ}]=i\hbar(g^{\mu\sigma}P^\rho-(\rho\leftrightarrow\sigma))$$
equivalent to writing
$$[P^μ,M^{ρσ}]=i\hbar(g^{\mu\sigma}P^\rho-g^{\mu\rho}P^\sigma)$$
if not, what does it mean?

Comment: Where did you see the left-right arrow notation? Though I suspect that your interpretation is correct, it might be useful to see the original source.

Comment: You are correct, this notation is relatively common (but pretty lazy), and usually means the same expression as given previously but with the two symbols exchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

$$ f(A,B) \pm (A\leftrightarrow B) ~:=~ f(A,B)\pm f(B,A). $$

The notation is useful as a shorthand, or to convey a symmetry/antisymmetry that may often otherwise be less apparent.

See e.g. the last equation in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/28559/2451) for a nested example.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen it either.  It looks like it means "a term just like the one I just wrote, but with the indicies $\sigma$ and $\rho$ exchanged."

Comment: I've seen it regularly and I can confirm that's what it means. (I would post an answer but it'd say the same thing as yours)

Comment: @DavidZ Post it as an answer, and I'll delete mine since you have definitive information.

Comment: Ah, looks like Qmechanic already did so.