# Commutation relations of generators of $SO(N)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, commutator, lie-algebra

> That is, $J_{i j}$ is a tensor. We can take this a step further, and let $R^{\prime}$ itself be an infinitesimal rotation, of the form $R^{\prime} \rightarrow 1+\omega^{\prime},$ with $\omega_{i j}^{\prime}=-\omega_{j i}^{\prime}$ infinitesimal. Then, to first order in $\omega^{\prime},$ Eq. $(4.1.9)$ gives
> $$
> \frac{i}{2 \hbar}\left[J_{i j}, \sum_{k l} \omega_{k l}^{\prime} J_{k l}\right]=\sum_{k l}\left(\omega_{i k}^{\prime} \delta_{j l}+\omega_{j l}^{\prime} \delta_{i k}\right) J_{k l}=\sum_{k} \omega_{i k}^{\prime} J_{k j}+\sum_{l} \omega_{j l}^{\prime} J_{i l}.
> $$
> Equating the coefficients of $\omega_{k l}^{\prime}$ on both sides of this equation gives the commutation rule of the $J$ s:
> $$
> \frac{i}{\hbar}\left[J_{i j}, J_{k l}\right]=-\delta_{i l} J_{k j}+\delta_{i k} J_{l j}+\delta_{j k} J_{i l}-\delta_{j l} J_{i k}. \tag{4.1.10}
> $$

This is a paragraph from Steven Weinberg's lecture of quantum mechanics. Can anyone help me solve the equation (4.1.10)?

These are the commutation relation of generators of $SO(N)$

Comment: what have you tried so far and where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: I have equated the coefficients of w and but don't know how to solve the last commutation relation

Comment: What do you mean by "solve"?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28535/2451

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your lecture, but, in the abstract, there is an infinity of solutions (representations) of (4.1.10) for the matrices $J_{ij}^{ab}$. The simplest one is the vector, *N×N* matrices,
$$
J_{ij}^{ab}= -i\hbar (\delta_i^a   \delta_j^b-  \delta_i^b  \delta_j^a      ).
$$
Can you check that?

Comment: Yes sir it worked. Can you suggest me some literature about this representation. I want to know the way we reach at this particular representation

Comment: It's a standard extension of the undergraduate [3D rotation algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra#Three_dimensions) to *N* dimensions, a parameterization of all antisymmetric matrices in that dimension. Most group theory books cover it. The Lorentz group is parameterized similarly. If you accept the answer, click on the checkmark.