# Group Theory Commutation Relations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, angular-momentum, group-theory, lie-algebra

Can someone help me prove these commutation relations?

$$[M_{ij},M_{kl}]=\delta_{jk}M_{il}+\delta_{il}M_{jk}-\delta_{ik}M_{jl}-\delta_{jl}M_{ik}$$

where $i, j, k, l$ run from $1$ to $3$.

And:

$$[M_{\mu\nu},M_{\lambda\rho}]=\eta_{\mu\rho}M_{\nu\lambda}+\eta_{\nu\lambda}M_{\mu\rho}-\eta_{\mu\lambda}M_{\nu\rho}-\eta_{\nu\rho}M_{\mu\lambda}~?$$

I know that $\partial_{i}x_{j}$ gives us $\eta_{ij}$, but why am I getting Kronecker delta in the first expression? Is it because of the Euclidean space? I read somewhere that $\partial_{i}x^{j}$ gives us $\delta_{i}^{j}$, then why am I getting Kronecker delta in the above expression instead of $\eta$?

Comment: What is $M$? How does this relate to derivatives of coordinates? Are you working in special relativity? You should provide more context to the problem you are having or it will be difficult for anyone to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28535/2451