# Deriving orthochronous proper Lorentz group generators

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, lie-algebra

From my lecture notes it seems to be possible to derive the generators of the orthochronous proper Lorentz group

$[J_{cd}]^a_b=i(\delta^a_c\eta_{bd}-\delta^a_d\eta_{bc})$

by equaling these two expression for the transformation:

$\Lambda^a_b\simeq \delta^a_b+\omega^a_b$

$\Lambda^a_b\simeq \delta^a_b-\frac{i}{2}\omega^{cd}[J_{cd}]^a_b$

Is it right? How to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28535/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic actually i would derive generators from these two expression, if it is possible, maybe using antisimmetry property of w. It seems to me that the answers in that question use different arguments